# Existence of a regular conditional distribution(rcd) implies existence of density for rcd?

Tags: probability-theory

Does the existence of a regular conditional distribution(rcd) imply the existence of a density for rcd? This question is motivated by the following example. The way it's written, seems to suggest so...

[image]

[This other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340456/existence-of-conditional-density-given-conditional-distribution) also seems to have the answer to mine. However, it's written in a very complex way, which honestly I don't understand.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, it does not. The example in no way suggests that the density exists in general.

Comment: @zhoraster Thanks for your comment. Could you give such an example? thanks

Comment: Example: $Y$ is any random variable without density and $X$ is constant.

Comment: @zhoraster thanks for the comment. If Y, X have a joint density and X has a marginal density, then can the conditional distribution, also have one? was this the point of the example? ;)

Comment: If there is a joint density, then there is both marginal density and the conditinal density. This is the point.